# Sum over relatively prime pairs

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $ A$ be the set of all ordered pairs $(p,q)$ of positive integers such that $gcd(p,q)=1$. For a certain positive real number $a>1$ $$\sum\limits_{(p,q) \in A}\frac{1}{a^{p+q}-1}=10000$$
Then find $a$. The summation looks so difficult, I do not have the slightest idea from where to begin. I need a basic help and gradually to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: This looks like a problem where you would work incrementally upwards using the $2$-element partitions of the integers which are greater than $1$, such as $(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),\dots$ (notably skipping e.g., $(2,2)$).

Answer (score 2):

Call the sum on the left $f(a)$.  You might start with
$$f(a) = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac{\varphi(n)}{a^n - 1}$$
Then look at the [Lambert series generating function for $\varphi$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Generating_functions).

Comment: Would we start with $n=1$ or $n=2$?

Comment: What then? I am sorry I find myself at zero level in this. Could you please write the next few steps. Thanks.

Comment: Good point, @abiessu.  I'll edit.

Comment: @You-know-me: then take $q = 1/a$, and solve $f(a) = 10000$ for $a$.

Comment: I am getting an irrational $a$...

Comment: @You-know-me What equation are you solving?

Comment: This http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10000%3D%281%2Fa%29%2F%281-%281%2Fa%29%29%5E2

Comment: You forgot to remove the $n=1$ term.